# Cannot format USB flash drive to FAT32 while writing Linux Mint Cinnamon Edge using Rufus

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, linux-mint, rufus

I wanted to install Linux MINT on my computer. I downloaded Mint and Mint Edge .ISO files. When I opened Rufus to write them to a USB flash drive, it couldn't format the disk to FAT32 when I selected the Edge version, however it worked fine when I selected the normal Cinnamon version.

I want to mention that the USB flash drive only has 8 GB of space, so that isn't the problem like many pages say.

[image: rufus screenshot]

This is what it looks like after writing:

[image: device manager windows]

Comment: Why do you want to use FAT32?

Comment: This ^^^ And do try GPT/UEFI instead. Or use a simpler tool like Balena Etcher so you don't have to deal with so many options. Or, even better, the multi-boot tool Ventoy.

Comment: Meanwhile take your time to read and understand how to dual-boot with any modern Windows in the proper UEFI mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi This one and your other question show that you're very, too much, "green" in this stuff.

Comment: Fixed in edge image (according to https://github.com/linuxmint/linuxmint/issues/622). Find them in the list of all versions: https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php

Answer (score 6):

Rufus dev here.

1. First of all, if you have an issue with Rufus, you should try to report it to the [official Rufus issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues) rather than a place where the application developers may not look.
2. When reporting an issue with Rufus, you should check what it says in its log, which can easily be accessed by clicking on the small blue notebook icon (left of `START`).
3. If you had checked the log, you would have seen that it said the following:

```
ISO label: 'Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon 64-bit'
  Size: 2.8 GB (Projected)
  Has a >64 chars filename
  Uses: Syslinux/Isolinux v6.04
  Uses: EFI
  Note: This ISO uses symbolic links and was not designed to work without them.
  Because of this, only NTFS will be allowed as the target file system.
```

4. The last 2 lines tell you everything you need to know, which is that the Linux Mint distro maintainers have designed their media to rely on symbolic links, and FAT32 does not have symbolic link. Therefore, if you were to use FAT32 as the file system, the media would not boot properly. As a result, and **since Mint boot media does work when using NTFS**, Rufus automatically selects NTFS for you, and does not allow the use of FAT32.

Now, the root of the problem here is that the Linux Mint folks **screwed up** their `linuxmint-21.2-cinnamon-64bit-edge.iso`, because, if you look at its content, you will find that the `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi`, i.e. the 64-bit UEFI bootloader for x86 systems, is a symbolic link that points to a file that does NOT exist on the ISO (because it points to `/etc/alternatives/shimx64.efi.signed` which probably existed on the developer's machine but is most certainly not present on the ISO-9660 file system). So, of course, when you create the media using *File System Transposition* (or ISO mode as Rufus calls it), the 64-bit UEFI bootloader will not work and the media will not boot, even though this has nothing to do with using NTFS.

You might be able to get a bootable media by using *DD Mode* when Rufus prompts you (Remember when you got a prompt from Rufus asking you whether you wanted to write the image in *ISO Mode* or *DD Mode*, and advising you to try *DD Mode* if you had an issue with *ISO Mode*?), but the main issue, really, is that the Linux Mint folks borked their `linuxmint-21.2-cinnamon-64bit-edge.iso` (but curiously, their `linuxmint-21.2-xfce-64bit.iso` is fine) and [I have now reported this to them](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/11924).

Comment: I tried today with the cinnamon edge image available to download. Still contains symbolic links.

Comment: I think the Edge image that contain a fix might take a few days to be published. In the meantime, I have just published Rufus 4.4 that adds a workaround for the issue. You can download it at https://rufus.ie.

Comment: Thank you! Windows seems to have updated Rufus silently today, cause I had no issues later today. -- Meanwhile, I switched to NixOS, which had no issues with the ISO image .

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using Ventoy and booting from there.

Comment: Meta commentary does not belong in the body of an answer.